# Is it possible to do array-wise operation on assignment?

Tags: python, pandas

I looked through Stack Overflow thoroughly and I couldn't find any helpful results. At this point I'm not even sure if this is possible, but because I'm only a beginner I thought I'd at least ask it here.

Basically, I have multiple data set, each with about 8 million rows and I do not want to loop over each row. I read at multiple places that vectorization is almost always the fastest operation with pandas DataFrames, but I can't think of a way to write my script without a loop. Speed is crucial because I'd rather not keep my computer running for a month straight.

I have to take two values from one DataFrame and use them as indices for the other DataFrame and change the value to 1. Suppose the following code:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
>>> df1.columns = ['A','B']
>>> df1
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(0, index = list(df1['B']), columns = list(df1['A']))
>>> df2
   1  3  5
2  0  0  0
4  0  0  0
6  0  0  0
```

Right now, I have a for loop that works like this:

```
>>> listA = list(df1['A'])
>>> listB = list(df2['B'])
>>> row_count = len(listB)
>>> for index in range(row_count):
...     col = listA[index]
...     row = listB[index]
...     df2[col][row] = 1
```

Using for loop over the `range()` iterator seems significantly faster than `iterrows()`. But I seek to make my script run as fast as it possibly can (because I have a gigantic amount of data) so I was wondering if I could get rid of the loop. I thought there would be a fair chance of pandas module having a method for DataFrames that I don't know that can do this work very efficiently.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: The possible duplicate does not address my problem because my goal is not to change diagonal values to 1; it was just a coincidence in my example because I have very simple DataFrames. Also, I'm sorry if this is not how I'm supposed to format edits; I'm new to this community.

Comment: You can just do `df2.loc[:,:] = 1`, this sets all values in the dataframe to 1.

Comment: @sirfz OP only wants to set those index pairs to 1 which are defined in `df1`, not all of them.

Comment: I've updated my answer so you can have a flag or a count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***answer***
option #6 is my best attempt.

***edit:***
For option 6 instead of overwriting the assignment, you can increment instead.  This small tweak should get you a count.

```
df2.values[row_indexers, col_indexers] += 1
```

***option 1***

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [1,6]], columns=['A', 'B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(0, index = list(df1['B'].unique()),
                    columns = list(df1['A'].unique()))

df1.groupby(list('AB')).size().gt(0).mul(1) \
    .reindex(df2.unstack().index, fill_value=0) \
    .unstack(0)
```

[image]

---

***option 2***

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [1,6]], columns=['A', 'B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(0, index = list(df1['B'].unique()),
                    columns = list(df1['A'].unique()))

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df1.values.T).drop_duplicates()
df2.update(pd.Series(1, mux).unstack(0))
df2
```

[image]

---

***option 3***

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [1,6]], columns=['A', 'B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(0, index = list(df1['B'].unique()),
                    columns = list(df1['A'].unique()))

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df1.values.T).drop_duplicates()
df2.where(pd.Series(False, mux).unstack(0, fill_value=True), 1)
```

[image]

---

***option 4***

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [1,6]], columns=['A', 'B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(0, index = list(df1['B'].unique()),
                    columns = list(df1['A'].unique()))

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df1.values.T).drop_duplicates()
df2[pd.Series(True, mux).unstack(0, fill_value=False)] = 1
df2
```

[image]

---

***option 5***

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [1,6]], columns=['A', 'B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(0, index = list(df1['B'].unique()),
                    columns = list(df1['A'].unique()))

for i, (a, b) in df1.iterrows():
    df2.set_value(b, a, 1)
df2
```

[image]

***option 6***
inspired by @ayhan and @Divakar

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [1,6]], columns=['A', 'B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(0, index = list(df1['B'].unique()),
                    columns = list(df1['A'].unique()))

row_indexers = df2.index.values.searchsorted(df1.B.values)
col_indexers = df2.columns.values.searchsorted(df1.A.values)

df2.values[row_indexers, col_indexers] = 1
df2
```

[image]

---

***timing***
***given sample***
***code:***

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [1,6]], columns=['A', 'B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(0, index = list(df1['B'].unique()),
                    columns = list(df1['A'].unique()))

def pir1():
    return df1.groupby(list('AB')).size().gt(0).mul(1) \
        .reindex(df2.unstack().index, fill_value=0) \
        .unstack(0)

def pir2():
    mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df1.values.T).drop_duplicates()
    df2.update(pd.Series(1, mux).unstack(0))

def pir3():
    mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df1.values.T).drop_duplicates()
    return df2.where(pd.Series(False, mux).unstack(0, fill_value=True), 1)

def pir4():
    mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df1.values.T).drop_duplicates()
    df2[pd.Series(True, mux).unstack(0, fill_value=False)] = 1

def pir5():
    for i, (a, b) in df1.iterrows():
        df2.set_value(b, a, 1)

def pir6():
    row_indexers = df2.index.values.searchsorted(df1.B.values)
    col_indexers = df2.columns.values.searchsorted(df1.A.values)

    df2.values[row_indexers, col_indexers] = 1
    return df2

def ayhan1():
    row_indexers = [df2.index.get_loc(r_label) for r_label in df1.B]
    col_indexers = [df2.columns.get_loc(c_label) for c_label in df1.A]

    df2.values[row_indexers, col_indexers] = 1

def jez1():
    return pd.get_dummies(df1.set_index('B')['A']).groupby(level=0).max()
```

[image]

***much larger sample***
***code:***

```
from itertools import combinations
from string import ascii_letters
letter_pairs = [t[0] + t[1] for t in combinations(ascii_letters, 2)]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=np.random.randint(0, 100, 10000),
                        B=np.random.choice(letter_pairs, 10000)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(0, index = list(df1['B'].unique()),
                    columns = list(df1['A'].unique()))
```

[image]

Comment: Do you use `df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6], [1,6]])`
`df1.columns = ['A','B']`
`df2 = pd.DataFrame(0, index = list(df1['B']), columns = list(df1['A']))` ?

Comment: I think need `df2 = pd.DataFrame(0, index = list(df1['B'].unique()), columns = list(df1['A'].unique()))`

Comment: And then `timings` will be great ;)

Comment: Selected for giving the fastest running snippet. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I think you need [`pd.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) but first [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from column `B`:

```
print (df1.set_index('B')['A']) 
B
2    1
4    3
6    5
Name: A, dtype: int64

print (pd.get_dummies(df1.set_index('B')['A']))
   1  3  5
B         
2  1  0  0
4  0  1  0
6  0  0  1
```

If duplicates, need `groupby` with aggregate `max`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6], [1,6]])
df1.columns = ['A','B']
print (df1)
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
3  1  6

df2 = pd.get_dummies(df1.set_index('B')['A'])
df2 = df2.groupby(level=0).max()
print (df2)
   1  3  5
B         
2  1  0  0
4  0  1  0
6  1  0  1
```

Alternative edit by DYZ (resets the index and refers to the column instead):

```
print(pd.get_dummies(df1.set_index('B')['A']).reset_index().groupb‌​y('B').max())
```

Comment: Does not work for `df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[1,6]])`. But this does: `pd.get_dummies(df1.set_index('B')['A']).reset_index().groupby('B').sum()`.

Comment: @DYZ - thank you, it is another solution. Or maybe `pd.get_dummies(df1.set_index('B')['A']).groupb‌​y(level=0).sum()` works too.

Comment: @DYZ - I am not sure if `sum` is good, because if double `1` need `1` s output, not `2`. so `max` is necessary if need only `1` and `0` in output. If need sum duplicates, `sum` is necessary.

Comment: I agree, `max()` is better.

Comment: added a 6th option that is very fast

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I have successfully run my script in only 7 hours, which is great compared to the anticipated 1 month runtime. I used everyone's solution (the question was oversimplifying my issue because my task was a bit too complicated to explain at the time), but I selected @piRSquared's answer because he did give the fastest running snippet.

Answer (score 3):

numpy supports that type of indexing/assignment. As far as I know, pandas does not have that capability.

Assume this is your DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((5, 5)), index=list('abcde'), columns=list('ABCDE'))

df
Out: 
     A    B    C    D    E
a  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
b  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
c  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
d  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
e  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

And this one has the indices:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'C1': ['a', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'd'], 
                    'C2': ['B', 'D', 'A', 'E', 'A', 'A', 'E']})

df1
Out: 
  C1 C2
0  a  B
1  c  D
2  a  A
3  d  E
4  e  A
5  b  A
6  d  E
```

You can drop the duplicate index pairs at this point by

```
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates()
```

Now, numpy supports `arr[df1.C1, df1.C2]` type of indexing but it requires integer indices - not labels. You can use `index.get_loc` for that; it is pretty fast.

```
row_indexers = [df.index.get_loc(r_label) for r_label in df1.C1]
col_indexers = [df.columns.get_loc(c_label) for c_label in df1.C2]
```

If you access the underlying numpy array by the values attribute of the DataFrame, you can do:

```
df.values[row_indexers, col_indexers] = 1

df
Out: 
     A    B    C    D    E
a  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
b  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
c  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
d  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
e  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

---

The question was about how to do assignment using arrays. Therefore I assumed `df2` already exists and looks like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [1,6]], columns=list('AB'))
rows = df1['B'].unique()
cols = df1['A'].unique()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(0.0, index=rows, columns=cols)

df2
Out: 
     1    3    5
2  0.0  0.0  0.0
4  0.0  0.0  0.0
6  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Now if you apply my solution the result will be the same:

```
row_indexers = [df2.index.get_loc(r_label) for r_label in df1.B]
col_indexers = [df2.columns.get_loc(c_label) for c_label in df1.A]


df2.values[row_indexers, col_indexers] = 1

df2
Out: 
     1    3    5
2  1.0  0.0  0.0
4  0.0  1.0  0.0
6  1.0  0.0  1.0
```

Again, this is a solution that assumes you already have `df2` and want to do assignment. `get_dummies` or `groupby` will just count the index pairs and will give you a binary matrix. If your primary goal is reshaping that probably makes more sense. But when you say assignment, I understand something more general (like `df2.values[row_indexers, col_indexers] += 3`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how does this example take duplicates into account? I was trying to do a test run of both yours and jezrael's responses with `df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6], [1,6]])` given by jezrael, and the script keeps throwing me `AssertionError: Number of manager items must equal union of block items # manager items: 3, # tot_items: 0`.

Comment: The example (`df1`) does not have duplicates as far as I can see? Can you show me how you executed that? Assuming it has duplicates and you want to ignore them, you can just do `df1 = df1.drop_duplicates()`

Comment: I think the most problematic is process duplicates only in one column like `df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6], [1,6]])`. What is better as `groupby` with `max`? If `8M` rows I think there can be more such duplicates.

Comment: @jezrael I don't see how duplicates in a single column would cause a problem? In the example above, there are 3 elements in the column A yet it works just fine.

Comment: I think if desired output is `6  1  0  1` in last row from `df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6], [1,6]])` - there is duplicates `1` in first column. So `drop_duplicates` cannot be used.

Comment: hmmm, I think desired output is `print (pd.DataFrame({'1': [1, 0, 1], '3': [0, 1, 0], '5': [0, 0, 1]}))` from `df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6], [1,6]])`, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @jezrael I've updated the post but I think OP should clarify the main goal here.

Comment: I borrowed a bit of your logic and things learned from divakar to come up with a very fast answer.  I must remember this for later use.

Comment: @piRSquared Nice solution. :)

Comment: Yes, I do already have df2, which is all zeros. I actually need two outputs - one with binary values and another with sum of all duplicates. So I need both get_dummies and your answer. I've been trying to mix and match all the answers I'm getting here and I've seen some great improvements. Thank you.

Comment: @Posh_Pumpkin Glad that it helped. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I have successfully run my script in only 7 hours, which is great compared to the anticipated 1 month runtime. I used everyone's solution (the question was oversimplifying my issue because my task was a bit too complicated to explain at the time), but I selected @piRSquared's answer because he did give the fastest running snippet.

Comment: @Posh_Pumpkin That's great to hear. Pure numpy is almost always faster.